# Element-wise product of dataframe and a series alongwith rolling sum within the group

Tags: python-2.7, dataframe, pandas-groupby, rolling-computation

I have a big dataframe `df` of len `n` (`n` ~ 2 million rows)  with columns `name` and `qty` and series `wt` of size `m`(`m` ~ 70). Within each group as defined by values in column `name`, I want to multiply `qty` with `wt` and do a rolling sum. For example, say `df` and `wt` are defined as below:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['abd']*3 + ['pqr']*5 + ['xyz']*8, 'qty':range(16)})
>>> df.iloc[2, 1] = np.nan
>>> df
       name qty
    0   abd   0
    1   abd   1
    2   abd NaN
    3   pqr   3
    4   pqr   4
    5   pqr   5
    6   pqr   6
    7   pqr   7
    8   xyz   8
    9   xyz   9
    10  xyz  10
    11  xyz  11
    12  xyz  12
    13  xyz  13
    14  xyz  14
    15  xyz  15
>>> wt = pd.Series([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4])
>>> wt
    0    0.1
    1    0.2
    2    0.3
    3    0.4
```

The desired output `wtdsum` is as follows:

```
       name qty wtdsum
    0   abd   0    0.2
    1   abd   1    0.1
    2   abd NaN    0.0
    3   pqr   3    5.0
    4   pqr   4    6.0
    5   pqr   5    3.8
    6   pqr   6    2.0
    7   pqr   7    0.7
    8   xyz   8   10.0
    9   xyz   9   11.0
    10  xyz  10   12.0
    11  xyz  11   13.0
    12  xyz  12   14.0
    13  xyz  13    8.6
    14  xyz  14    4.4
    15  xyz  15    1.5
```

Adding some sample computations for `wtdsum` below:
RowId 0: `0*0.1 + 1*0.2 + NaN*0.3 = 0.2`
RowId 1: `1*0.1 + NaN*0.2 = 0.1`
RowId 2: `NaN*0.1 = 0.0`
RowId 3: `3*0.1 + 4*0.2 + 5*0.3 + 6*0.4 = 5.0`
RowId 4: `4*0.1 + 5*0.2 + 6*0.3 + 7*0.4 = 6.0`
RowId 5: `5*0.1 + 6*0.2 + 7*0.3 = 3.8`
RowId 6: `6*0.1 + 7*0.2 = 2.0`
RowId 7: `7*0.1 = 0.7`
RowId 8: `8*0.1 + 9*0.2 + 10*0.3 + 11*0.4 = 10.0`
... 
RowId 15: `15*0.1 = 1.5`

Comment: Could you please elaborate? How do you calculate each element in wtdsum?

Comment: @Let'stry please see the sample computations added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it goes, it's done in [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x), I hope it will not be a problem. It's a little bit tedious, but I will try to explain:

- First we create a variable `"indicator"` that will tell us how many elements of the current group remain. The first term in the `.apply()` creates a vector with the maximum number of occurences for each `"name"`. Then we substract the number of occurences that have already taken place in each row. Hence we obtain the number of remaining cases for each specific `"name"`. Then we take the minimum between this number and the length of `wt`.
- Then we use `.apply()` to perform the computations based on this `"indicator"`. In this second `.apply()`, we basically perform the computations you explained in your question based on how many cases remain for each `name`.

  ```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['abd']*3 + ['pqr']*5 + ['xyz']*8, 'qty':range(16)})
    df.iloc[2, 1] = np.nan

    wt = pd.Series([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4])

    df["indicator"] = np.minimum(df["name"].map(dict(df.fillna(0).groupby("name").count()["qty"])) - \
                                 df.groupby("name").cumcount(),
                                 len(wt))

    df["wtsum"] = df.apply(lambda x: np.sum(np.asarray((wt[range(0,x[2])]))*\
                                     np.asarray(df.fillna(0).iloc[list(range(x.name,x.name + x[2])),1])),\
                           axis = 1)

    df[["name","qty","wtsum"]]
  ```

  Output:

  ```
        name  qty   wtsum
    0   abd   0.0   0.2
    1   abd   1.0   0.1
    2   abd   NaN   0.0
    3   pqr   3.0   5.0
    4   pqr   4.0   6.0
    5   pqr   5.0   3.8
    6   pqr   6.0   2.0
    7   pqr   7.0   0.7
    8   xyz   8.0   10.0
    9   xyz   9.0   11.0
    10  xyz   10.0  12.0
    11  xyz   11.0  13.0
    12  xyz   12.0  14.0
    13  xyz   13.0  8.6
    14  xyz   14.0  4.4
    15  xyz   15.0  1.5
  ```

Comment: Thanks @Letstry. Do you think lambda function will make it slow for very large dataframes? Also can you explain the logic in this apply step?

Comment: I would have to try it, can't say it right now. Another way you can study is with `.rolling()`, but given that your rolling parameter is not constant I think it would be difficult. You could study also how to paralellize the task. Check the edit and let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @Letstry what if instead of `name` there are two columns to groupby?

Comment: I think you have to do the `map()` "manually" to the two columns and then just groupby by both of them `df.groupby(["another_col", "name"]).cumcount()`. The rest should be the same. But do not mix questions, create a new one in case you need it.

Comment: I am getting `NameError: ("global name 'wt' is not defined" , u'occurred at index 0')` in the line with `lambda` function. Any thoughts?

Comment: This error seems more related with how you structured your program (like you are using a function and you didn't pass `wt` through the input...)